# How to bypass: remote: GitLab: Author <non-member-email-here> is not a member of team?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, githooks, git-remote

I have a GitLab project (origin) that was originally cloned from another GitHub project (github).

```
$ git remote
github
origin
```

I made this happen by:

```
git remote add github https://the-git-hub-remote.git
```

Now I want to merge GitHub's new changes into my local code. so I did the following

In my local computer, I pulled changes from GitHub

```
git fetch github
```

I then copy the GitHub's `master` branch into a local branch called `github-master`

```
git checkout -b github-master github/master
```

Now I want to push it to my GitLab repo but it complains:

```
$ git push origin
Enumerating objects: 6813, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6083/6083), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1842/1842), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5721/5721), 2.09 MiB | 42.05 MiB/s, done.
Total 5721 (delta 4008), reused 5313 (delta 3735)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (4008/4008), completed with 224 local objects.
remote: GitLab: Author 'brian.riley@ucop.edu' is not a member of team
To my-git-lab-remote.git
 ! [remote rejected]   github-master -> github-master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@my-git-lab-remote.git'
```

What should I do?

Basically, I have the same problem as Velmurugan Velayutham in https://gist.github.com/DavideMontersino/810ebaa170a2aa2d2cad

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As illustrated in [issue 17244](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/17244), check the configuration of the project hook:

```
Check whether author is a GitLab user
Restrict commits by author (email) to existing GitLab users
```

You could at least ask to desactivate temporarily said hook, to allow your initial push to complete.

Comment: Same problem here. Would be nice to know how to disable the preinstalled GitLab wide hook. Currently I do not find the hook in the filesystem, nor do I find a possibility how to disable it in the UI. UI shows no hooks at all.

Comment: @defoe Do you have access to the GitLab server? Or is it gitlab.com?

Comment: I do have access to the GitLab server, it's a local instance.

Comment: @defoe Then check in the bare repo/hooks folder (repository storage path: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/repository_storage_paths.html), and see if there is a symlink in place in that `hooks` subfolder.

Comment: Thanks for your help, turns out it was a push rule within the local repository.

Comment: @defoe Interesting. A pre-receive hook of some kind then? (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/push_rules/push_rules.html)

Comment: Yes it's the "Check whether author is a GitLab user" push rule.

Comment: @defoe How did you disabled it?

Comment: It's a local GitLab instance, so I have access to the repo settings.